# Same MySQL query time varies between 0 and 30 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I tried to look for an already existing answer but found thousands of results about long query time. So sorry if this has already been asked.

I have a simple select query which is run twice during page load (one of them is always hidden) and I noticed that the second time it never takes more than 0.02 secs. But the first run does take even more than 30 secs sometimes even though we're talking about only a few hundred records. When I refresh the page it is fast sometimes then slows down again. The database itself does not change.

My question is where to start looking at?

The site:
http://www.autonextleltar.hu/index2.php

Here's my code:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT d_code, d_name FROM assets WHERE act = 1 GROUP BY d_code");
while ($rw=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {

    $d_code=$rw[d_code]; // dealer code
    $d_name=$rw[d_name]; // dealer name

    // now check if the status of all the dealer's vehicles are "ok" 

    $okq=mysql_query("SELECT status FROM assets WHERE d_code='$d_code' AND act = 1 GROUP BY status") or die(mysql_error());  
    $oknum=mysql_num_rows($okq); // if there are more than 1 rows then surely not every vehicle are "ok"
    $okrw=mysql_fetch_assoc($okq);
    $st=$okrw["status"];

    echo "<li><a href=\"#\">".substr($d_name,0,27)."</a>";
    if ($st=="ok" and $oknum==1) echo " (ready)";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

There's a database of vehicles and each vehicle is stored at a dealer. The site lists all dealers where there's at least one active vehicle. Inside this loop, there's another query, to check whether all the vehicles of the actual dealer have an "ok" status - if this is the case, the dealer is ready for further processing so we put a "ready" remark in brackets.

The table has like 600 records and looks like this:

```
1   id  int(11)         
2   d_code  int(11) 
3   d_name  varchar(200)    latin2_hungarian_ci
4   status  varchar(50) latin2_hungarian_ci
5   act tinyint(1)
```

I thought this was simple enough not to hassle with indexing but apparenty I was wrong. Query sometimes a few seconds but sometimes more than a minute. As soon as I remove the "inner" query (so without checking vehicle status) it is normal again (< 0.02 secs).

Thank you

Comment: this going to be closed if you don't show the query, the db schema, and some actual benchmark results

Comment: Sure. I'll narrow it down and post it soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that, after the statement is executed the first time, it is being stored in [MySQL's query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html), so that the second execution is simply fetched from the cache.

If the query takes that long, I'd bet it's performing a full table scan. Try [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)ing the query to see if you're missing a critical index.

Comment: answering bad questions encourages more

Comment: You are right thanks nevertheless. I'll post it soon.